# Error after accidentally deleting Podfile

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I made a huge mistake by deleting one podFile I had in my Xcode iOS application. I thought that the error was coming from that file when Instead it was another.
Long story short, I deleted the LevelDB pod and now the application is giving me this error after trying to launch it:

```
duplicate symbol '_pb_field_iter_find' in:
/Users/andreagualandris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstagramClone-agfsqctheamzqfcdwrbfiaaauqhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common 2.o
/Users/andreagualandris/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InstagramClone-agfsqctheamzqfcdwrbfiaaauqhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/pb_common.o.
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
```

I don't know how to move from here; Do I have to reinstall the podfile? Can I solve this problem by doing something else? thank you to whoever can help me.

Comment: try to see if you can pull those files from git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the terminal, run `pod install` in your project directory and it should be OK.

Comment: I did and the problem has been solved, but now I see another error coming from a pod file called leveldb. In particular in this line of code **memory_usage_.NoBarrier_Store(**  I'm receiving an error that says `No member named 'NoBarrier_Store' in 'std::__1::atomic<unsigned long> `

Answer (score 0):

Clear derived data. Try to run pod install then and build the app.

Comment: I did and the problem has been solved, but now I see another error coming from a pod file called leveldb. In particular in this line of code **memory_usage_.NoBarrier_Store(** I'm receiving an error that says `No member named 'NoBarrier_Store' in 'std::__1::atomic<unsigned long>'`

Comment: Try clearing pods cache and updating pod. These command might help
rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update